# The function mask_ is interrupted by asynchronous exception

Tags: haskell, exception, asynchronous

```
import Control.Exception
import System.Timeout
import Control.Concurrent

maskWorker :: IO ()
maskWorker = mask_ $ do 
      threadDelay 10000
      putStrLn $ "Return"

uninterruptWorker :: IO ()
uninterruptWorker = uninterruptibleMask_ $ do
      threadDelay 10000
      putStrLn $ "Return"

test :: IO () -> IO ()
test worker = do
             pid <- forkIO worker
             threadDelay 5000
             throwTo pid UserInterrupt
             threadDelay 15000
             putStrLn "The end"
```

The function mask_ should ignore the asynchronous exception till it returns. But "test maskWorker" doesn't print "Return". Why?

Comment: The following operations are guaranteed not to be interruptible: everything from Control.Exception except for throwTo ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mask` doesn't block all async exceptions, it just postpones them until the next [interruptible action](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#interruptible). Use `uniterruptibleMask` to block all async exceptions.